# How to Handle reactive forms with html select?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, reactjs, typescript

I have a template like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <mdl-textfield type="text" #userFirstName name="lastName"
              label="{{'FIRSTNAME' | translate}}" pattern="[A-Z,a-zéè]*"
              error-msg="{{'FIRSTNAME' | translate}}" floating-label
              formControlName="firstName">
  </mdl-textfield>
  <mdl-textfield type="text" #userLastName name="firstName" pattern="[A-Z,a-z,éè]*"
             label="{{'LASTNAME' | translate}}"                       
             error-msg="{{'LASTNAME' | translate}}" floating-label                                                          
             formControlName="lastName">
  </mdl-textfield>
  <mdl-textfield type="text" name="town" #userTown label="{{'TOWN' | translate}}"
                pattern="[A-Z,a-z,éè]*"
                error-msg="{{'TOWN' | translate}}" floating-label
                formControlName="town">
  </mdl-textfield>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield"> {{ 'COUNTRY' | translate }}
   <select name="country">
     <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country"          
         [selected]="country.id" 
         formControlName="countryId" ngDefaultControl>{{country.countryName}}
     </option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <mdl-card-actions>
    <button (click)="modifyClient()" [disabled]="!form.valid" 
         class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent">  
         {{'MODIFY' | translate}}
    </button>
  </mdl-card-actions>
 </form>
```

with text fields and a select. In reality I have 2 Select but to shorten the code, I have suppressed one here.

My component is:

```
public form: FormGroup;
    public countries;
    public languages;
    private id;
    private user: Client = new Client();
    public firstName = new FormControl('');
    public lastName = new FormControl('');
    public town = new FormControl('');
    public company = new FormControl('');
    public countryId = new FormControl('');
    public languageId = new FormControl('');
 ngOnInit()
    {
        this.getCountries();
        this.getLanguages();
        this.id = this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().id;
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            'firstName': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().firstName,
            'lastName': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().lastName,
            'town': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().town,
            'company': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().company,
            'countryId': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().countryId,
            'languageId': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().languageId
            });
        this.form.valueChanges
            .map((formValues) => {
                formValues.firstName = formValues.firstName.toUpperCase();
                return formValues;
            })
            // .filter((formValues) => this.form.valid)
            .subscribe((formValues) => {
                console.log(`Model Driven Form valid: ${this.form.valid} value:`, JSON.stringify(formValues));
            });
    }
```

So here everything is ok, the information is coming from the backend and it works greats.
When I change a value on textfields, **this.form.valueChanges** is called and the formValues and written in the console.
My problem is with Select Tags. If I choose another than the one by default, there is no change in the form and **this.form.valueChanges** is not called...

Any idea on how I could resolve that?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formControlName should be on the `<select>` but you have it on the `<option>`.

Comment: Works perfectly. I should have seen it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should not set an option as selected in the template, set the formControl's value and it will automatically select the option.

Comment: You are sure? I have : **<select name="country" formControlName="countryId">
                                <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="countryId" ngDefaultControl>{{country.countryName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>** and       **this.form = this.fb.group({
            'countryId': this.clientApi.getCachedCurrent().countryId
             });** that are correclty initialized but that does not work ...:(

Comment: Each of your options should have a different value, yours has the same value for all the options, countryId. Try `[value]="country.id"`, if that doesn't work, please ask a new question so it can be helpful to others who search for a similar problem